# Packer Cannot SSH into Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh-keys, packer

I have a Jenkins pipeline that is meant to automate the process of creating my images on AWS.
I don't want Packer to SSH into the instance using their temp keypair. I have added to the Packer template :

```
 ssh_clear_authorized_keys = true
 ssh_port                  = 22
 ssh_username              = "ubuntu"
 ssh_keypair_name          = "shell-ireland"
 ssh_certificate_file      = "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
 ssh_agent_auth            = true
```

The error I'm receiving is

```
--> amazon-ebs.ebs-build: Timeout waiting for SSH.
```

I have copied the key to the Jenkins server and still, nothing works.
This works on my local machine but not on the Jenkins server. The only change is the path.

Comment: Set verbose logging with `PACKER_LOG=1` to debug why the timeout occurs.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that ? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The timeout errors are usually caused by a problem in a security group configuration. Please make sure your instance security group allows traffic on port 22 from your Jenkins server?

Comment: Packer creates its own temp security group [0.0.0.0/0] for port 22, by default, and I've left it as such. 
My Jenkins server security group is only open for my IP Address.